# pdf and cdf of discrete RV X

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I just came across a new word DF in probability. What does it mean ? density function or distribution function ?

> What do you mean by pdf , cdf, pmf , and DF for a discrete random variable? Is pdf different from cdf ? i know how to find cumulative. But i don't know how to differentiate between pdf and pmf ? how to derive from each other ?

**Example**
Like if a discrete random variable is given as $x={1,2,3}$ and probabiltites respectively are ${0.1,0.3,0.6}$ Then i guess pmf is easy which is probability mass function as
$$
p_X(x)=\begin{cases}0.1,& x = 1 \\ 0.3,& x=2 \\0.6,& x=3 \end{cases}
$$

The next question is: If $Y=F_X(X)$ the DF of random variable X. **My try is shown which is correct but for next I am confused**
$$F=0.1 , 0.4,1$$
NExt question: How to find DF and pmf of Y ?? how to do ?

Comment: In your final line DF stands for "distribution function" and means the same as CDF

Comment: "What do you mean by pdf , cdf, pmf , ..." Aren't these defined in your notes/books? A google search reveals the definitions.

Comment: i got it .. but those wikipidea formulas are not working for my discrete varaible

Answer (score 2):

**pmf**: probability mass function is for discrete rv's

**pdf**: probability density function is for continuous rv's

**cdf**:  cumulative distribution function is used for both families

**DF**:  in general is Distribution function, say the CDF. When you are asked to find the DF, the Law of probability I think you can get either pmf of cdf (if discrete)

Note: in your post I do not see the question you are asked to respond. I guess you are asked to find Y Law....

Comment: No. pmf is for discrete rv while pdf is for continuous...the former is a probability function, the latter is not. In continuous rv's the probability is an area